# XBMC audio language media flag

Tags: kodi

I have movies on my HDD what are dubbed to my mother-language. Others are in english. Now started using XBMC for playing movies. With many movies in a library, when browsing movies I need to know what are dubbed and what are in english.

Is possible to setup XBMC to scan audio-language in movie filenames and show it in a movie browser? Something like:

```
 Movie_name-YEAR-CZaudio.mpg     #for czech dubbing
```

Or here is some other recommented solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XBMC "Movie sets" and/or Tags, whichever suits your case better.

XBMC - KODI wiki has more information:

- [Movie sets](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Movie_sets)
- [Video library tags](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Video_library_tags) (since v12 Frodo)